# Change UInavigationbar title back page

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

i have two screen. i want click button first screen after navigation bar change in second screen.
i using storyboards

first screen code

```
-(IBAction) ChangeSecondPageTitle: (id) sender {

SecondViewController *second=[[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"second"];
        second.modalTransitionStyle=UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
          second.detailTitle.topItem.title=@"example";
        [self presentModalViewController:second animated:YES];
}
```

second screen.h

> @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UINavigationBar *detailTitle;

Comment: What is your question? Where is your code? What have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guessing you are trying to set title for your second screen navigation bar.

Use a navigation controller to present your second screen.

In SecondDetailViewController instance, maintain a NSString property.

`@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *navBarTitle;`

In viewDidLoad, just set the title.

`[self setTitle:navBarTitle];`

Comment: but string will be the first view

Answer (score 2):

Actually the reason your code is not working is you set the property to your nav bar and then your `viewDidLoad` get called. In `viewDidLoad` it loads the nib file and return new allocated navBar. So to Solve this take a global string set it from first view and then in second in `viewDidLoad` set your `navbar`'s `title`. Follow 
Adithya's answer for that.

Answer (score 1):

In second screen declare a property

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *newTitle;
```

and in viewDidLoad

```
     self.title  = _newTitle;
```

and in your first screen

```
  ...
  second.newTitle = @"NEW_TITLE";
```